# Zero not displaying as 0 when printing from array

Tags: c++

Everything works as expected except when the number of seconds equals a 4 or a multiple of 4.
When this is the case the 0 for seconds is displayed as something other than zero.

Please explain to me why this is happening.

**When seconds = 3, the output is:**

```
Please enter the height of the bridge (meters): 100
Please enter the time the watermelon falls: 3
Time Falling (seconds) Distance Falling (meters)
*************************************************
0   0
1   4.9
2   19.6
3   44.1
```

**When seconds = 4 the output is:**

```
Please enter the height of the bridge (meters): 100
Please enter the time the watermelon falls: 4
Time Falling (seconds) Distance Falling (meters)
*************************************************
1117572301  0
1   4.9
2   19.6
3   44.1
4   78.4
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//declare variables
int seconds, heightBridge, count;
float heightWatermelon, maxFall;
const float gravity = 9.8;

//get variables from user
cout << "Please enter the height of the bridge (meters): ";
cin >> heightBridge;

cout << "Please enter the time the watermelon falls: ";
cin >> seconds;

//declare array's
int secondsArray[seconds];
float heightWatermelonArray[seconds];

for (count = 0; count <= seconds; count++)
    {
    heightWatermelon = 0.5 * gravity * count * count;
    secondsArray[count] = count;
    heightWatermelonArray[count] = heightWatermelon;
    }

//create heading
cout << "Time Falling (seconds) Distance Falling (meters)\n";
cout << "*************************************************\n";

//calculate max fall distance
maxFall = 0.5 * gravity * seconds * seconds;

//display data
for (count = 0; count <= seconds; count++)
    {
    if (maxFall > heightBridge)
        {
        cout << "Warning - Bad Data: The distance fallen exceeds the "
             << "height of the bridge" << endl;
        break;
        }
    else
        cout << secondsArray[count] <<  "\t"
             << heightWatermelonArray[count] << endl;
    }


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your arrays as follows:

```
//declare array's
int secondsArray[seconds];
float heightWatermelonArray[seconds];
```

Then access in the following loop:

```
for (count = 0; count <= seconds; count++)
```

When you declare an array of length `seconds`, this allocates an array with `seconds` number of elements. Because arrays are zero-indexed, this means that the indices `0..(seconds-1)` are valid. Your loop will go from `0..seconds`, hence will cause an overflow. To fix, simply change the `<=` to `<`.

The other solution is to resize your arrays as Zeta says below. In this case, just change your array specification to the following:

```
//declare array's
int secondsArray[seconds+1];
float heightWatermelonArray[seconds+1];
```

You're then probably wondering why you get a weird number instead of zero there. Because on x86 (I assume you're on x86), the stack grows downwards, `heightWatermelonArray` will be directly *before* `secondsArray` in memory. When you write to `heightWatermelonArray[seconds]` (i.e off the end of `heightWatermelonArray`, you overflow the array, then go to the next bit of memory. In this case, that memory will be the first element of `secondsArray`, and so you corrupt memory.

Comment: Actually, using `seconds + 1` storage would be a better solution, since OP is interested in the height after `seconds` time.

Comment: @Zeta - I actually noticed that just now after properly re-reading the spec. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation slugonamission!

Answer (score 4):

You are using indices from `0` to `seconds` (including), hence your array must be declared as

```
int secondsArray[seconds+1];
float heightWatermelonArray[seconds+1];
```

(it only *seems* to work with smaller values, your code is actually invoking undefined behaviour).